# Kibana sometimes returns completely irrelevant results

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

We are using Logstash, elasticsearch and kibana for handling and searching of our logs.

Often, we searching, Kibana will return results that do not contain the searched for item.

For example, we search on the exact phrase - here is the query

```
    curl -XGET 'http://logs.magick.nu/kibana2/logstash-2014.10.17,logstash-2014.10.16/_search?pretty' -d '{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "should": [
            {
              "query_string": {
                "query": "COND_30892c7a490e154e01490e2dcf7a0008(2)"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "range": {
                "@timestamp": {
                  "from": 1413471279957,
                  "to": 1413557679958
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "highlight": {
    "fields": {},
    "fragment_size": 2147483647,
    "pre_tags": [
      "@start-highlight@"
    ],
    "post_tags": [
      "@end-highlight@"
    ]
  },
  "size": 500,
  "sort": [
    {
      "@timestamp": {
        "order": "desc",
        "ignore_unmapped": true
      }
    },
    {
      "@timestamp": {
        "order": "desc",
        "ignore_unmapped": true
          }
        }
      ]
    }'
```

And Kibana would return results such as:

```
    {
  "_index": "logstash-2014.10.17",
  "_type": "app SwitchYard",
  "_id": "unti1lWJRTelQd4N5_LVjA",
  "_score": null,
  "_source": {
    "message": "2014/10/17 13:50:43,739 [com.domain.Connector.service.ent.BasicJMSTickListener] (NJ4X-63) Sending market info for product symbol to JMS topic. Broker Server: broker.Demo. Account Number: 1235. StrategyId: 4028e49447ac4296147af921d5f00b. OrderCount: 2",
    "@version": "1",
    "@timestamp": "2014-10-17T14:24:32.193Z",
    "type": "app SwitchYard",
    "tags": [
      "node"
    ],
    "domain": "trading1-magickdev.amakitu.com",
    "env": "DEV",
    "host": "nodelarge.amakitu.com",
    "path": "/var/lib/openshift/541723389821cc77c2000167/jbosseap/logs/server.log"
  },
  "sort": [
    1413555872193,
    1413555872193
  ]
}
```

This happens a lot!

Any ideas what is wrong?

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing the exact query. Use the kibana "inspect" button to show the full query to elasticsearch.

Comment: Hi Roman, I've updated my question to show that the exact query.

Comment: I still don't see the query...

Comment: also, while your at it, post the mapping for the app SwitchYard type

Comment: Hi Roman, I've added exact query. Will return with mappings.

Comment: Ok, i see the query. Now tell me, what documents do you expect such a query should return? please give a concrete full json document that you think matches the query.

Comment: HI Roman, I would expect that if I type "COND_30892c7a490e154e01490e2dcf7a0008(2)" in the search box, that results would contain this.